# 2018 Mac Mini 4k Scaling issue

Tags: display, mac-mini, gpu, 4k

I just bought a 2018 Mac Mini (3.2 GHz i7) and three 4k monitors (one 32 inch and two 27 inch). The setup is great, but there is one flaw. 4k is too small! This is a common complaint and while Apple lets you scale them to a more usable size, there must be a lot of graphical interpolation going on as the scaling is not 1:1. So when I scale my monitors, everything is much more readable, but when I type, the characters are delayed when being written on the screen. It’s as if it is lagging behind and can’t keep up drawing the letters as I type them.

So my question is, if I got an eGPU, and connected all my monitors to that, would it solve this problem?

Bonus points, does anyone have an eGPU set up they recommend or have had success with? My guess is I don’t need much power as I am an Android developer (but still use iPhone because it’s just better…), and all I want it to be able to type smoothly again.

Comment: My guess is that it will fix the problem for you - the eGPU setup definitely will have lots more processing power. However, I haven't actually tried and tested it with 3 x 4k monitors, so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: In case you haven't come across it yet, you may like to visit [eGPU.io](https://egpu.io).

Answer (score -1):

If you had a larger monitor, the problem would go away. I also have a 2018 Mac Mini. I am using a 49" 4K TV as a monitor. There's no scaling going on, and it looks great. The TV is a TCL brand. Maybe the 49" size is a bit extreme -- I guess the 43" model might be better for most people. But, text is large enough without any scaling, and typing is responsive. The display is 3840x2160, and the Mac thinks it is driving a 36-inch display.

I'm driving the TV using HDMI. The MacMini only has one HDMI port, so if you want three of them, you'll need some adapters.

Figuring out where to put three 40-something inch monitors where you can see them all is another problem, I guess.